# Push History in Reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, push

Is there a way to not repat this piece of code?

```
     onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              history.push(`/Post-Review/${tagResult.PostId}`);
            }}
```

I need to use this piece of code in different places, I don't want to repeat i.

is it possible to create a function and use the function name instead of this code?

thanks:)

Comment: Depends on context; if "different places" means outside of closures that have `history` and `tagResult` available you'd have to provide them somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const historyPushFunc = (e , tagResult)  =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  history.push(`/Post-Review/${tagResult.PostId}`);
}
```

Now you can use  it anywhere like this:

```
onclick={e => historyPushFunc(e, tagResult) }
```

You can also pass extra arguments to the function if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i got an error, 

 Line 34:  'tagResult' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @John , you need to pass `tagResult` as an argument in `historyPushFunc` , like this `historyPushFunc(e , tagResult)` ,  I have **edited** the answer you can see it.

Comment: Yeah, i did but, but before it was working without refreshing the page, and no, it refreshing the whole page, is there a way to not refresh it?

Comment: @John, sometimes it's just a glitch . Try restarting your development server and opening the page in new tab.